# SQL Join to each row of a bridge table (filtering)

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

In the equivalent of an Amazon product filter I have product classification ids coming from the front end as a table of ids. Each product can have many classifications. A normal join with my bridge table (ProductIds and ClassificationIds) returns products that have ANY of these ids. However I would like to return only those products that have ALL of the ids, thus meeting all of the customer's desires. An AND not an OR. How do I do this?

For example this is the typical join with test data for classification ids:

```
DECLARE @ClassifcationIds dbo.IdsTableNullable
INSERT INTO @ClassificationIds (Id) 
VALUES (1),(2),(3)

 SELECT DISTINCT 
              Id
              Description
        FROM dbo.Products as P
             JOIN dbo.ProductClassification AS Pc ON P.Id = Pc.ProductId
             JOIN @ClassifcationIds AS C ON C.Id = Pc.ClassificationId;
```

This returns products that have classification ids 1, 2, or 3. I only want products that have all three.
What is the equivalent of joining the bridge table on the first id, then joining the resulting table to the next id and so on until the resulting products have all 3 classification ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Description
FROM dbo.Products P JOIN
     dbo.ProductClassification Pc
     ON P.Id = Pc.ProductId JOIN
     @ClassifcationIds C
     ON C.Id = Pc.ProductId
GROUP BY p.Id, p.Description
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @ClassifcationIds);
```

Comment: You might want `having count(distinct C.Id) ...`.